# Android Widget size incorrect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `4 x 1` widget that shows up as:

`4 x 1` widget on `Galaxy Nexus`
but shows up as
`3 x 1` widget on `Motorola RAZR`with `ICS`

I am following the guidelines provided at the below url
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size

```
android:minHeight="40dip"
android:minWidth="250dip"
```

Not sure what could be causing this problem. I can fix the issue by changing the `minWidth` value to 270dp but I dont want to do this without understanding the problem. One additional note, I am not using any preview images for my widgets.

Appreciate any insight one can provide on this.

Comment: Dip's are device independent hence the use different native units on different screen sizes.

Comment: Well they're supposed to be, but I'm facing same problem here. Widget takes 4x2 on GN, but only 3x2 on SGS3 and RAZR...

Answer (score 0):

Do both of your phones run ICS? They changed the widget cell size from Gingerbread to ICS. I had the same problem but since Google came out with multiple .apk support for the same app I put the new sizes into the targetSDK:16 version of the app and never had to worry about it. I'm sure you could just use a v-14 folder and duplicate the widget's XML file and put the new sizes in the XML file located in the v-14 folder. If both phones are ICS than I'm not sure what to tell you. You could always make your widgets resizeable too